# Importing text with pandas/python

Tags: python, pandas

I am importing a table with some text in it into a pandas dataframe. One of the strings contains the text 'NF-κB' - i.e. the 'kappa' character (some of the text in the tables also contains alphas and betas etc.).

When I read in the table using:

```
pd.read_table('table_processed.txt', sep='\t')
```

The kappa character is converted to '\xce\xba' so that part of the string now reads 'NF-\xce\xbaB' when viewed in iPython.

Is there any way to maintain string encoding during the import to maintain the kappa charater when the string is viewed as part of the dataframe?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Straight from the docs, try using an encoding

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/io.html#dealing-with-unicode-data

```
In [1079]: data = 'word,length\nTr\xe4umen,7\nGr\xfc\xdfe,5'

In [1080]: df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), encoding='latin-1')

In [1081]: df

      word  length
0  Träumen       7
1    Grüße       5

In [1082]: df['word'][1]
u'Gr\xfc\xdfe'
```